# Pandas, Seaborn, Plot boxplot with 2 columns and a 3º as hue

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

in a Pandas Df with 3 variables i want to plot 2 columns in 2 different boxes and the 3rd column as hue with seaborn

I can reach the first step with pd.melt but I cant insert the hue and make it work

This is what I have:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'A':['a','a','b','a','b'],'B':[1,3,5,4,7],'C':[2,3,4,1,3]})
df2=df[['B','C']].copy()
sb.boxplot(data=pd.melt(df2), x="variable", y="value",palette= 'Blues')
```

[image]

I want to do this in the first DF, setting variable 'A' as hue
Can you help me?

Thank you

Comment: Could you draw a form of the desired graph in detail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, you can achieve this as follows:

- Apply [`df.melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html#pandas.DataFrame.melt), using column `A` for `id_vars`, and `['B','C']` for `value_vars`.
- Next, inside [`sns.boxplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.boxplot.html), feed the melted df to the `data` parameter, and add `hue='A'`.

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame({'A':['a','a','b','a','b'], 'B':[1,3,5,4,7], 'C':[2,3,4,1,3]})

sns.boxplot(data=df.melt(id_vars='A', value_vars=['B','C']), 
            x='variable', y='value', hue='A', palette='Blues')

plt.show()
```

**Result**

[image: boxplot]